# Syskey to ignore specific .dll file?

Tags: windows-7, dll, ignore, syskey

Is it possible to have Syskey ignore a specific .dll file in the system32 folder on Windows 7?
I have installed another program which requires the .dll file, however, that file makes Syskey crash when I select "Password Startup".

When I remove that file from system32 and reboot, Syskey works fine but my other software doesn't.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can the dll go in the program folder for the program rather than system32?

Comment: Unfortunately the program does not have a folder, it is a hidden logger.